# Как прокрутить страницу на несколько пикселей вверх?

Tags: javascript

При переходе по якорной ссылке браузер не до самого верха прокручивает страницу и остается небольшой отрезок от другой секции. Как сделать так, чтобы этого отрезка не было?
Пытался сделать это с помощью window.scrollBy, но не получилось его вписать в сам код пролистывания

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')

  for (let anchor of anchors) {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href')
      document.querySelector('' + blockID).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start"
      })
    })
  }
```

Сам сайт ilyin1ib.beget.tech

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]